# How to use ServerSocket to activate the event ServerSocketClientRead to listen from client socket

Tags: serversocket, c++builder-6

I'd like to ask a question.
   I am using borland C++ builder 6, and i have a `ServerSocket`,now i need to open a connection  and to listen from client socket. my code is like that

```
sktServerSocket->Port=  80;
sktServerSocket->Active=True;
sktServerSocket->Open();
if(sktServerSocket->Socket->Connected)  {
  int y=0;
}
```

and here in the event of ServerSocketClientRead I have

```
void __fastcall TFormServer::sktServerSocketClientRead(TObject *Sender,
      TCustomWinSocket *Socket)
{
  int iTest=0;
}
```

when I try to debug the program,i found the code

```
if(sktServerSocket->Socket->Connected)
```

is true, but it will never go to code in

```
TFormServer::sktServerSocketClientRead
```

I'd like to ask,is there any error in my code of connecting server?
in which case the event `ServerSocketClientRead` will be executed?
   Thank u very much for ur kindness help

btw i think i know
  when ClientSocket->Socket->SendText(tbxClientText->Text);  is executed,ServerSocketClientRead is activated

Comment: You don't "connect to a client socket" - you open a server socket, and wait for the client to connect to you. The "sktServerSocket->Socket->Connected" just means the server socket is listening, not that there are any clients yet.   There is an event that fires for client connecting and client activity. I'm not at my dev PC at the moment but I'll write a good answer tomorrow if Remy doesn't get here first.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Feel free to answer this one :)